# Filter NSArray using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array which contains strings. Some of these string might be empty (@""). How does the predicate have to look like so that it filters the array and returns a new one containing only non empty strings:

Array A: {"A","B","","D"} -> FILTER -> Array B: {"A","B","D"}

and it should also return this:

Array A: {"","","",""} -> FILTER -> Array B: {}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use predicate `SELF != ''` if you are filtering just array of `NSString`s. This matches every `NSString` which is not exactly equal to empty string.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Example code:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"A", @"B", @"", @"C", @"", @"D"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Input array: %@\nFiltered array: %@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@","], [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

Gives this output

```
Input array: A,B,,C,,D
Filtered array: A,B,C,D
```

Edit: Joris Kluivers posted solution with predicate format `length > 0`. This is probably better solution just for removing empty string as it will probably be much faster.

Answer (score 7):

Check for the length of the strings:

```
NSArray *values = @[@"A", @"B", @"", @"D"];
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"];

NSArray *filteredValues = [values filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Results in the required array `("A", "B", "C")`

Comment: +1 Nice solution, didn't know about this one. Will probably be much faster than my solution comparing agains empty string. I have edited my answer mentioning your answer ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c]%@",searchText];

[arrSearched removeAllObjects];

[arrSearched addObjectsFromArray:[self.arrContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

here arrContent is original array and arrSearched is output array after search.